# print console characters faster

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, bit

I have a function that accepts a number which will convert it to a 5x7 graphic representation of digits like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(" ███ ");  // byte: 0000 1110
Console.WriteLine("█   █");  //       0001 0001
Console.WriteLine("█   █");  //       0001 0001
Console.WriteLine("█   █");  //       0001 0001
Console.WriteLine("█   █");  //       0001 0001
Console.WriteLine("█   █");  //       0001 0001
Console.WriteLine(" ███ ");  //       0000 1110
```

I was told it can be done faster using byte arrays.
This is basically what I did:

```
byte[] data = new byte[] { 14, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 14 };
BitArray bitData = new BitArray(data);


int bitCounter = 0;
foreach (bool bit in bitData)
{ 
  if (bit)   
    Console.Write("█");
  else 
    Console.Write(" ");
  bitCounter++;
  if (bitCounter>7)
  { 
    bitCounter=0;
    Console.WriteLine();
  }
}
```

This is slower than what is started with so I can't use it.
Can anyone show me a better way?

Update:
StringBuilder does help, but it will be a bit slower than the original code I had.  Its still basically using the write command 7 times in the console is slowing me down.
I tried using using just 1 write command using \n, but I need to indent the next line without erasing inside the indented spaces.

Comment: Well, of course it is slower, you have so much more `Write` calls here. What you can do is to create one string, with new lines embeded, and try to put it on console at once. I don't know what was meant by saying you can do it faster using arrays, but probably not what you understood

Comment: You can use `StringBuilder` to create an entire line (or the entire output) first and output it to screen in its entirety.

Comment: Or you can try something like Example 2 from this link: http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-string-byte-array it seems to be using arrays, but it all falls back to outputing one string to console instead of many

Comment: @Davio `StringBuilder` will be slower if the string is know from beginning. If he will simply create one string in code, compiler will optimize it nicely

Comment: Of course, you can always add a lookup table with all 256 different possible strings. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Minimized IO. Here is a version below that makes console calls only at the end.

```
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        bitCounter = 0;
        foreach (bool bit in bitData)
        {                
            if (bit)
                stringBuilder.Append("█");
            else
                stringBuilder.Append(" ");
            bitCounter++;
            if (bitCounter > 7)
            {
                bitCounter = 0;
                Console.WriteLine(stringBuilder.ToString());
                stringBuilder.Clear();
            }
        }
```